# R How to plot a graph with multiple geom

Tags: r, ggplot2

The problem comes when I tried to add one more variable, the number of flights, in the last line of my code.
Can I add more than one geom, which unit of x-axis and y-axis are not necessarily the same?   Thank you

```
library(nycflights13) 
library(tidyverse)
flights %>% 
mutate(
    cancelled_flights = is.na(dep_delay),
    sched_dep_time.HMM = sched_dep_time %/%100 + (sched_dep_time%%100)/60,
    sched_dep_time.byH = sched_dep_time.HMM %/%1) %>%
group_by(sched_dep_time.byH) %>%
summarise(
    delay_prob = sum(is.na(dep_delay)) / n(),
    count = n()) %>%
filter(sched_dep_time.byH >=2) %>%
ggplot() + 
geom_path(mapping = aes(x = sched_dep_time.byH, y = delay_prob)) +
geom_col(mapping = aes(x = sched_dep_time.byH, y = count ))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

The only reason why your plot isn't showing is due to the different y-axis values for `delay_prob` (0.005 to 0.04) and count (1061 to 27242).

Here's a way to play around with a second y-axis to show both plots:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = sched_dep_time.byH)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = delay_prob), colour="red") +
  geom_bar(aes(y=count/1000000), stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1000000, name = "count"))
```

[image]

Alternative approach by plotting different plots on with facet_wrap:

```
df <- df %>% gather(type, val, delay_prob, count)

ggplot(df, aes(sched_dep_time.byH, val)) + 
  geom_bar(data=df %>% filter(type=="count"), stat="identity") + 
  geom_line(data=df %>% filter(type=="delay_prob")) +
  facet_wrap(~type, scales="free", ncol=1)
```

[image]

Input data:

```
df <- flights %>% 
   mutate(
    cancelled_flights = is.na(dep_delay),
    sched_dep_time.HMM = sched_dep_time %/%100 + sched_dep_time%%100)/60,
    sched_dep_time.byH = sched_dep_time.HMM %/%1) %>%
  group_by(sched_dep_time.byH) %>%
  summarise(
    delay_prob = sum(is.na(dep_delay)) / n(),
    count = n()) %>%
  filter(sched_dep_time.byH >=2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Adam. It is sth more than helpful.